# Is it safe to use Bash 4 features in new scripts?

Tags: bash, portability

Bash 4 offers some nice features like globstar, associative arrays, the mapfile builtin etc.

Will it greatly decrease the portability of my scripts if I make use of these features? Is it safer to stick to Bash 3?

Comment: I guess it depends what OSes you are targetting - you rule out all Apple OS X boxes if you use `bash4` since Apple hasn't got beyond `bash 3.2`.

Comment: I don't really see how this can be answered other than with the phrase _it depends_....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on how portable you want to be.

Apple does not ship Bash 4 on Mac OS X since Bash 4 uses the GPLv3. Of course, users can install it themselves if they want, but most users won't have it.

If you want to be portable to OS X, you probably shouldn't rely on Bash 4 features. However, if you don't mind just being portable to modern GNU/Linux distros, then pretty much all of them include Bash 4, so you might as well rely on them.

Also, do recall that not all OS's even ship bash by default. For instance, OpenBSD ships pdksh by default, and you need to explicitly install Bash. Debian ships bash, but `/bin/sh` is Dash, so you need to explicitly use `#!/bin/bash` if you want to opt in to Bash specific features.

If you really want portability, you should stick to POSIX/Single-Unix-Specification features. However if all you need is to run on the latest GNU/Linux distros (and even ones a few years old), using `/bin/bash` and assuming it's Bash 4 should be fine.

Comment: I'd also suggest that Python 2.x or Perl serve as kind of a lingua franca across *nix systems -- you're covered on OS X and every Linux distro I can think of. For genuine portability, Python seems like a better bet than Bash, anyway, since Bash scripts would require more external commands in the host system, so you're stuck with POSIX if you want to really be portable, and that's indeed limiting. (Of course, sometimes Bash is still the better tool for the job.)

Comment: @IvanX Python isn't included in the Arch Linux [base packages](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/i686/base/), and if you do install it, `/usr/bin/python` is Python 3, not Python 2 (which you need to refer to as `python2` explicitly). It looks like [neither Python or Perl are included in base OpenBSD](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/). Embedded Linuxes like OpenWRT generally don't include either in their base distro. If you want true portability, POSIX `sh` is the way to go. If not, use whichever you prefer, as all are available in package repos on pretty much all platforms.

Comment: Thanks Brian, didn't know that about Arch and Python. There is Perl, though, if you're not targeting embedded linuxes. I just always feel so hamstrung when working with POSIX `sh`, but sure, your point holds.