# Whether to redirect stderr to stdout OR redirect both to the same file?

Tags: shell

Which is better?

- `cmd >>file 2>&1`
- `cmd 1>>file 2>>file`

Is there even a difference?

---

I know two reasons to choose the first one: It does also work with `>` instead of `>>`. It is more popular, therefore someone knowing shell-scripts would except it right away.

But, I still feel like the second one is better readable, and works without having to know the `[n]>&[n]` syntax, which IMHO is kinda confusing.

Comment: Does having two open file descriptions (with their own, mostly meaningless file offsets) count as a difference?

Comment: You would generally see to 2nd form as `cmd 1>>outfile 2>>errfile` (that is the only benefit from using two descriptors)

Comment: In modern shells, you would just use `&>>` (bash) or `>>&` (tcsh).

Comment: Or for bash, simply `&>file` if redirecting both.

Comment: @DavisHerring if it is an actual issue, (speed / max open files / ...) that should be taken into account. But I would rather like to know if having two file descriptor would make a real difference like mixing up the sequence of the output

Comment: @DavisHerring: What do you mean by "modern", AFAIK bash and tcsh are older than busybox's ash and Debian's dash

Comment: @Sam: I mean that bash doesn’t have `&>>` (just `&>`, `>>`, and `>&`) until version 4, which some [still don’t have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30708549/8586227).

Comment: @Sam: Not with append.  NFS 3 has a broken append mode, but it should work even there since it’s all on one machine.

Comment: Are there really less file-descriptors in the first alternative? I don't know how it is implemented in the kernel, but afai can tell a unnamed fifo (when /proc/self/fd/2 points do somethink that is not a file) is also an open file descriptor. Having that output appended to the target of stdout (the file) would not reduce the number of file descriptors, would it? Does having file descriptors pointing to an actual file a negative effect compared to the "not realy a file"-once?

Comment: @Sam, you have two file descriptors, but they're just pointers to the same kernel structure. There is genuinely only one object backing both file descriptor numbers in the `>output 2>&1` case.

Answer (score 3):

### What is the difference?

Let's examine what each of these commands means.  I will assume that the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) applies since the question doesn't ask about anything more specific.

The first command is `cmd >>file 2>&1`.  This runs `cmd` after setting up the specified redirections.

The redirection [`>>file`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_03) opens the named file with `O_APPEND`.  As explained in the specification of [`open`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), this creates a new [Open File Description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_258), which notably contains the current file offset, and arranges for [File Descriptor](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_166) 1 to refer to that description.  The meaning of [`O_APPEND`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is "the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write".

The redirection [`2>&1`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06) says that file descriptor 2 "shall be made to be a copy" of file descriptor 1.  That specification is a little vague, but I think the only sensible interpretation (and what shells actually do) is it means to call [`dup2(1, 2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html), which "shall cause the file descriptor [2] to refer to the same open file description as the file descriptor [1]".  Crucially, we get another file *descriptor*, but continue to use the same file *description*, meaning they both have the same file offset.

The second command is `cmd 1>>file 2>>file`.  Based on the specifications cited above, this creates two separate file descriptions for `file`, each with their own offset.

Now, if the only thing that `cmd` does to file descriptors 1 and 2 is to call [`write`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html), then these two situations are **equivalent**, because every call to `write` will atomically update the offset to point to the end of the file before performing the write, and therefore the existence of two separate offsets in the second command will not have any observable effect.

However, if `cmd` performs some other operation, for example [`lseek`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html), then the two cases are **not equivalent** because that will reveal that the first command has one shared offset while the second command has two independent offsets.

Additionally, the above assumes the POSIX-specified semantics of `O_APPEND`.  But real computer systems do not always implement that; for example, [NFS does not have atomic append](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_a9).  Without atomic append, the second command may behave differently (most likely corrupting the output) even when only `write` is performed.

### Which is better?

As the two commands do not mean the same thing, which is better presumably depends on which meaning is closer to what you intend.  I speculate that, in almost all cases, the intent is to append to `file` both the standard output and standard error from `cmd`, which is presumed to only `write` to these descriptors.  That is precisely the meaning of the first command (`cmd >>file 2>&1`), and hence is the better choice.

While the second command does use fewer shell features, and hence might be easier to understand for some people, it would probably seem odd to those who *do* have greater familiarity with redirection syntax, and might even behave differently than intended in some circumstances.  Therefore I would advise against it, and if I found it in some code I was maintaining, would be inclined to change it to the first form.

Of course, if you truly want separate file descriptions, and hence separate file offsets, then the second command makes sense, so long as you put a comment nearby explaining the rationale for the unusual construction.